# Kendo UI modal with Gaussian blur

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

It is possible if I wanted to substitute the default grey background of the modal kendo window with a nice gaussian blur like in the image below? [Here I provide Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ugEVafIb)

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your main content (the div that contains all the text) a class too, and then blur that class when  the window is opened:

```
<div id="maincontent">This is the main body text</div>

function onOpen() {       
    let main = document.getElementById("maincontent")
    main.style.filter = "blur(2px)"
}
```

In your code snippet I have used the P tag to blur:

[image]